Как в Fedora поменять сочитание клавиши с super + space на ctrl + Lshift?
Установил дистрибутив fedora budgie spin и нужно поменять сочтётеи в настройках ни как не могу поменять сочитание клавиши для смены раскладки языка с super + space на ctrl + Lshift.

Поставь пакет gnome-tweaks
Там на кнопке дополнительно можно добавить сочетания клавиш на переключение раскладки.
Эта опция меняет схему /org/gnome/desktop/input-sources/xkb-options в dconf добавив 'grp:ctrl_shift_toggle'

Спасибо за ответ!
